# Neutron agents does not displayed. Ussuri

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-neutron

The neutron agents are not displayed.  At the same time, the agents themselves as a service are started correctly.
Dhcp, l3, openvswitch do not work.  The metadata-agent is displayed and running.

/var/log/neutron/ reports this information in all three agents:

```
2021-02-05 14:53:04.271 24955 INFO neutron.common.config [-] Logging enabled!
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 INFO neutron.common.config [-] /usr/bin/neutron-dhcp-agent version 16.3.0
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 CRITICAL neutron [-] Unhandled error: ValueError: No closing quotation
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/bin/neutron-dhcp-agent", line 10, in <module>
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron     sys.exit(main())
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/cmd/eventlet/agents/dhcp.py", line 17, in main
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron     dhcp_agent.main()
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/agent/dhcp_agent.py", line 46, in main
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron     config.setup_privsep()
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neutron/conf/agent/common.py", line 261, in setup_privsep
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron     priv_context.init(root_helper=shlex.split(get_root_helper(cfg.CONF)))
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shlex.py", line 305, in split
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron     return list(lex)
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shlex.py", line 295, in __next__
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron     token = self.get_token()
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shlex.py", line 105, in get_token
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron     raw = self.read_token()
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shlex.py", line 187, in read_token
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron     raise ValueError("No closing quotation")
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron ValueError: No closing quotation
2021-02-05 14:53:04.272 24955 ERROR neutron
```

Tell me, please, what's the matter?

Comment: "no closing quotation" looks like a syntax error in the DHCP agent config, probably a missing quote character. I'd fix that first. However there might be other problems, such as agents being unable to communicate with the Neutron server.

Comment: And because of what can there be no communication between agents and the server?  I installed it according to the instructions.  Didn't turn off Network Manager.  There are 4 interfaces available.  enp0s3, enp0s8, enp0s8, br-int

Comment: There are many different possibilities. Which instructions did you follow? There are many as well.

Comment: Actually, NetworkManager might be a problem. I don't think that Ussuri Neutron supports it.

Comment: In general, I did everything according to this lesson - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7P6bUejf6o&list
The Network Manager was not turned off there.

Comment: I have two more errors in the logs. One is associated with Rabbit and the other with Keystone.

Comment: It's very hard to comment, because the video starts after installation of some OpenStack services. It seems that it's similar to the install guide on docs.openstack.org. Can you describe the setup - how many nodes, are you using provider or tenant networks? Also add the RabbitMQ errors to the question. RabbitMQ is essential for communication between Neutron components.

Comment: 1)  WARNING keystonemiddleware.auth_token [- - - - -] AuthToken middleware is set with keystone_authtoken.service_token_roles_required set to False. This is backwards compatible but deprecated behaviour. Please set this to True.
2) WARNING amqp [- - - - -] Received method (60, 30) during closing channel 1. This method will be ignored.
-
Could this make a difference to the Neutron?

Comment: Since the Metadata agent is listed, there seems to be no fundamental communication problem. Can you check the agents' logs? Also don't forget to review the DHCP agent config.

Comment: The Keystone warning can be ignored. I am not sure if the RabbitMQ warning is relevant.

Comment: I have three nodes. The first is the controller, the second is computing, the third is storage.
On the controller at the moment: keystone, glance, nova, placement, neutron.

Comment: As for the agent logs. All three agents with whom there are problems have the same entries in the logs, as indicated at the beginning of the topic.

Comment: There is also such an error:
ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connection failed: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED (retrying in 2.0 seconds): ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED

Comment: *connection refused* occurs normally at startup. It's only problematic during operation. Since the metadata agent could connect to the Neutron server, it's unlikely that Rabbit causes your problem.

Comment: It looks like a problem with Openvswith when I started using Linuxbridge the agents started. Because of what could this be?

Comment: I don't want to speculate before you fix the DHCP configuration and check the agents' log files. Most probably your problem is caused by an incorrect comma somewhere, or something similar. Unfortunately, a video is not ideal for checking configuration file contents. My recommendation is using the official tutorial at http://docs.openstack.org/install-guide.

Comment: "All three agents with whom there are problems have the same entries in the logs" You mean the quotation error? As I said, double-check the configuration files. I also recommend enabling debug logging (if not done yet) to have more error context.